# The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is 

Tags: wsdl, apache-axis

I have been struggling with the following error the last couple of
days can you please help!

I generated my server and client code using the wsdl2java tool from a
wsdl 2.0 file.
When invoking the webservice I am getting the following error:

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The endpoint reference (EPR) for the
Operation not found is
/axis2/services/MyService/authentication/?username=Denise345&password=xxxxx
and the WSA Action = null
```

My service is displayed on the axis2 webpage with all available methods.
Here is the output from TcpMon

```
==============
Listen Port: 8090
Target Host: 127.0.0.1
Target Port: 8080
==== Request ====
GET /axis2/services/MyService/authentication/?username=Denise345&password=xxxxx
HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: ""
User-Agent: Axis2
Host: 127.0.0.1:8090

==== Response ====
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: application/xml;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 12 May 2011 15:53:20 GMT
Connection: close

12b
<soapenv:Reason xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soapenv:Text xml:lang="en-US">The endpoint reference (EPR) for the
Operation not found is
/axis2/services/MyService/authentication/?username=Denise345&password=xxxxx
and the WSA Action = null</soapenv:Text></soapenv:Reason>
0
```

==============

I am using:

- axis2-1.5.4
- Tomcat 7.0.8
- wsdl 2.0 file

Please help!

Answer (score 26):

In my case it was caused by a wrong `Content-Type` in the HTTP POST. Setting it to `text/xml` solved the problem.

Comment: You a genius bro tnx bb

Answer (score 15):

Try adding `?wsdl` to the string.

Comment: What does this query string do/mean?

Answer (score 7):

As described by Eran Chinthaka at http://wso2.com/library/176/

> If Axis2 engine cannot find a service and an operation for a message,
>   it immediately fails, sending a fault to the sender. If service not
>   found - "Service Not found EPR is " If
>   service found but not an operation- "Operation Not found EPR is  and WSA Action = "

In your case the service is found but the operation not. The Axis2 engine uses SOAPAction in order to figure out the requested operation and, in your example, the SOAPAction is missing, therefore I would try to define the SOAPAction header

Answer (score 5):

It happens because the source WSDL in each operation has not defined the SOAPAction value.

e.g.

```
<soap12:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
```

His is important for axis server.

If you have created the service on netbeans or another, don't forget to set the value action on the tag @WebMethod

**e.g. @WebMethod(action = "hello", operationName = "hello")**

This will create the SOAPAction value by itself.

Answer (score 4):

This error is coming because while calling the service, it is not getting the WSDL file of your service.

Just check whether WSDL file of your service is there--> run server and from browser run axis 2 apps on local host and check the deployed services and click on your service, then it shows WSDL file of your service.....or check the service path in your client file.

I hope it may help you to resolve the problem.

Comment: For me, it was same as above. i.e. I was pointing to wrong WSDL file, which off-course did not had the desired operation. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Action is *null* means that no Action in given SOAP Message (Request XML). You must set Action before SOAP call:

```
java.net.URL endpoint = new URL("<URL>"); //sets URL

MimeHeaders headers = message.getMimeHeaders(); // getting MIME Header

headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", "<SOAP Action>"); //add Action To Header

SOAPMessage response = soapConnection.call(<SOAPMessage>, endpoint); //then Call

soapConnection.close(); // then Close the connection
```

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem using curl to send a soap request. Solved it by adding "content-type:  text/xml" to the http header.

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: This helped me. I was using "application/xml" and when I switched to "text/html" the problem went away...

Comment: Sorry if this is a dummy question but how this could be added to the http header?

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved by disabling validation

```
<proxy>
    <!-- . . . -->
    <parameter name="disableOperationValidation">true</parameter>
</proxy>
```

Comment: Your solution worked for wso2 micro integrator 1.2.0!

Answer (score 1):

Late answer but:

I see you do a GET - should be a POST ?

Answer (score 0):

try removing the extra '/' after the operation name (authentication) when invoking through the client

```
/axis2/services/MyService/authentication?username=Denise345&password=xxxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems don't find wsdl file..
I've solved adding wsdlLocation parameter at javax.jws.WebService annotation

Answer (score 0):

By removing cache wsdl-* files in /tmp folder, my problem was solved

see https://www.drupal.org/node/1132926#comment-6283348

be careful about permission to delete

I'm in ubuntu os

Answer (score 0):

On Websphere Application Server, in the same situation, it helped deleting the Temp folders while the server was stopped.

I ran into the situation when the package of the service changed.

Answer (score 0):

Open WSDL file and find:

```
<soap:operation soapAction="[actionNameIsHere]" style="document"/>
```

Add to the requests header [request send to service]:

```
'soapAction' : '[actionNameIsHere]'
```

This work for me.

For devs. using node-soap [ https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap ] - example:

```
var soap = require('soap');
var options = {
   ...your options...
   forceSoap12Headers: true
}
soap.createClient(
        wsdl, options,
            function(err, client) {
                if(err) {
                    return callBack(err, result);
                }
                client.addHttpHeader('soapAction', '[actionNameIsHere]');
                ...your code - request send...
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because the SOAP request I was sending to the server was malformed and had an empty Body

In this case the error message from the server is misleading and can be solved changing the request content, without changing anything about operations, URLs, WSDL, etc