# The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found

Tags: web-services, exception, wsdl, tomcat7, apache-axis

I started learning Web Services. I wrote my first piece of code from the example that was given in the book. But when i run it, it does not behanve the way its supposed to! I see the wsdl file generated and see the error:

My WSDL file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://ts.ch01" xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:impl="http://ts.ch01" xmlns:intf="http://ts.ch01" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">  
<!--WSDL created by Apache Axis version: 1.4  
Built on Apr 22, 2006 (06:55:48 PDT)-->  
 <wsdl:types>  
  <schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://ts.ch01" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">  
   <element name="getTimeAsString">  
    <complexType/>  
   </element>  
   <element name="getTimeAsStringResponse">  
    <complexType>  
     <sequence>  
      <element name="getTimeAsStringReturn" type="xsd:string"/>  
     </sequence>  
    </complexType>  
   </element>  
   <element name="getTimeAsElapsed">  
    <complexType/>  
   </element>  
   <element name="getTimeAsElapsedResponse">  
    <complexType>  
     <sequence>  
      <element name="getTimeAsElapsedReturn" type="xsd:long"/>  
     </sequence>  
    </complexType>  
   </element>  
  </schema>  
 </wsdl:types>  

   <wsdl:message name="getTimeAsStringResponse">  

      <wsdl:part element="impl:getTimeAsStringResponse" name="parameters">  

      </wsdl:part>  

   </wsdl:message>  

   <wsdl:message name="getTimeAsElapsedResponse">  

      <wsdl:part element="impl:getTimeAsElapsedResponse" name="parameters">  

      </wsdl:part>  

   </wsdl:message>  

   <wsdl:message name="getTimeAsElapsedRequest">  

      <wsdl:part element="impl:getTimeAsElapsed" name="parameters">  

      </wsdl:part>  

   </wsdl:message>  

   <wsdl:message name="getTimeAsStringRequest">  

      <wsdl:part element="impl:getTimeAsString" name="parameters">  

      </wsdl:part>  

   </wsdl:message>  

   <wsdl:portType name="WSNewTestImpl">  

      <wsdl:operation name="getTimeAsString">  

         <wsdl:input message="impl:getTimeAsStringRequest" name="getTimeAsStringRequest">  

       </wsdl:input>  

         <wsdl:output message="impl:getTimeAsStringResponse" name="getTimeAsStringResponse">  

       </wsdl:output>  

      </wsdl:operation>  

      <wsdl:operation name="getTimeAsElapsed">  

         <wsdl:input message="impl:getTimeAsElapsedRequest" name="getTimeAsElapsedRequest">  

       </wsdl:input>  

         <wsdl:output message="impl:getTimeAsElapsedResponse" name="getTimeAsElapsedResponse">  

       </wsdl:output>  

      </wsdl:operation>  

   </wsdl:portType>  

   <wsdl:binding name="WSNewTestImplSoapBinding" type="impl:WSNewTestImpl">  

      <wsdlsoap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>  

      <wsdl:operation name="getTimeAsString">  

         <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>  

         <wsdl:input name="getTimeAsStringRequest">  

            <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>  

         </wsdl:input>  

         <wsdl:output name="getTimeAsStringResponse">  

            <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>  

         </wsdl:output>  

      </wsdl:operation>  

      <wsdl:operation name="getTimeAsElapsed">  

         <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>  

         <wsdl:input name="getTimeAsElapsedRequest">  

            <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>  

         </wsdl:input>  

         <wsdl:output name="getTimeAsElapsedResponse">  

            <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>  

         </wsdl:output>  

      </wsdl:operation>  

   </wsdl:binding>  

   <wsdl:service name="WSNewTestImplService">  

      <wsdl:port binding="impl:WSNewTestImplSoapBinding" name="WSNewTestImpl">  

         <wsdlsoap:address location="http://localhost:9090/WSTestOther/services/WSNewTestImpl"/>  

      </wsdl:port>  

   </wsdl:service>  

</wsdl:definitions>
```

I am not sure what other information to provide, if you need anything just ask. I am using Tomcat 7.0

Also I see the error in console:

```
[ERROR] The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is /WSTestOther/services/WSNewTestImplService and the WSA Action = null. If this EPR was previously reachable, please contact the server administrator.  
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is /WSTestOther/services/WSNewTestImplService and the WSA Action = null. If this EPR was previously reachable, please contact the server administrator.  
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.DispatchPhase.checkPostConditions(DispatchPhase.java:102)  
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:329)  
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:262)  
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:168)  
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.util.RESTUtil.invokeAxisEngine(RESTUtil.java:144)  
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.util.RESTUtil.processURLRequest(RESTUtil.java:139)  
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet$RestRequestProcessor.processURLRequest(AxisServlet.java:837)  
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doGet(AxisServlet.java:273)  
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)  
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)  
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)  
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)  
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)  
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)  
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)  
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)  
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)  
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)  
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)  
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)  
[WARN] Deprecated usage of OMElement#declareNamespace(String,String) with empty prefix
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981379/the-endpoint-reference-epr-for-the-operation-not-found-is