# JAX-WS service cannot talk to another

Tags: websphere, jax-ws

We have a JAX-WS servce on one node of our WebSphere 8.5.5 box, and it needs to talk to a JAX-WS service on another node on the same box.  It's been doing this in WebSpere 7 for months.

Yet suddenly, it won't.  I wish I could say that ONLY the server version changed, but no, lots of code changed.  But that code is now working on a WebSphere 7 box.  So it seems like it's a version thing.

I can call the service that is being called by the other service with a unit test and it works fine.

The called service does not seem to report an exception.  The calling service complains:

```
    [8/29/14 14:59:49:222 EDT] 0000007d AxisEngine    E org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine receive The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is {correct URL redacted) and the WSA Action = . If this EPR was previously reachable, please contact the server administrator.
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is (correct URL redacted) and the WSA Action = . If this EPR was previously reachable, please contact the server administrator.
at org.apache.axis2.engine.DispatchPhase.checkPostConditions(DispatchPhase.java:102)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:329)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:360)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:195)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.WASAxis2Servlet.doPost(WASAxis2Servlet.java:1583)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:66)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:960)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1064)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:909)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:283)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)
```

Comment: If you changed WebSphere version maybe host/ports have changed and are not updated in the client?

Comment: Check a following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981379/the-endpoint-reference-epr-for-the-operation-not-found-is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's what happened.  Actually about half a dozen things went wrong at the same time which lead to people looking for solutions in the wrong places.  But this particular error seemed to have come from a set of .class files that were not checked in in the .apt_generated folder after a recent change to the interface of the web service being called.

Once checked in, the deployment workspace got them, and all worked.