# Axis SOAP call in https (vs. http)

Tags: java, web-services, soap, https, axis

I'm trying to call a SOAP webservice through https with the following code:

```
    String endpoint="https://xxx";
    doc =  XmlUtils.stringToDoc(xmlStr);
    Service service = new Service();
    Call call = (Call) service.createCall();
    call.setTargetEndpointAddress(endpoint);
    call.setSOAPActionURI(soapAction);
    // Create SOAP Envelope
    SOAPEnvelope se = new SOAPEnvelope();
    se.getBody().addDocument(doc);
    _in.setString("P","invoking "+call.getTargetEndpointAddress());
    output = (SOAPEnvelope) call.invoke(se);
```

When I do this invocation, I get this error:

> {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is http://xxx and the WSA Action = com:StatemgrtMgr
>   Service/SuspendRequest. If this EPR was previously reachable, please contact the server administrator.

the address seems to be changed from https to http (what would explain not finding the webservice).

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981379/the-endpoint-reference-epr-for-the-operation-not-found-is)

Comment: My main concern is the change from https (in the code) to http (in the error message). The wsdl can be found at xxx?wsdl.

Comment: Does the WSDL itself specify `http` or `https` in `wsdl:service/wsdl:port/soap:address@location` ?