# The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found when invoking proxy service in WSO2 ESB

Tags: soap, wso2, wso2-esb

I'm using wso2 esb 5.0. I created the proxy service for invoke soap endpoint. Below mentioned the proxy service code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="LicenseRenewalSystem"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="http,https">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log/>
         <property expression="get-property('transport','VehicleNo')"
                   name="vehicleNo"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <log>
            <property expression="get-property('default','vehicleNo')" name="VehicleNo"/>
         </log>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                                 xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
                                 xmlns:sam="http://sample.esb.org">
                  <soapenv:Header/>
                  <soapenv:Body>
                     <sam:getPolicyID>
                        <sam:vehicleNumber>$1</sam:vehicleNumber>
                     </sam:getPolicyID>
                  </soapenv:Body>
               </soapenv:Envelope>
            </format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('default','vehicleNo')"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <log level="full"/>
         <property name="ContentType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="text/xml"/>
         <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" value="text/xml"/>
         <call>
            <endpoint>
               <address format="soap12"
                        uri="http://172.17.0.1:9763/services/EmissionTestService?wsdl2"/>
            </endpoint>
         </call>
         <log level="full"/>
      </inSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

I used header value (VehicleNo) to pass the proxy service. 
But I invoke this proxy using postmen, below error is occurred.

```
The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is http://172.17.0.1:9763/services/EmissionTestService and the WSA Action = null. If this EPR was previously reachable, please contact the server administrator.
```

Can anyone help me to slove this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind errors comes up when the related WSDL file for the proxy is not found. Please make sure that the Endpoint that you are calling is available in the ESB instance.

Please refer to the guide for more info. https://wso2.com/library/176/

Also a similar kind of question is answered here. [The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981379/the-endpoint-reference-epr-for-the-operation-not-found-is)