# SOAP web service call using WebServiceTemplate in SpringBoot client

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, soap-client

I am calling a SOAP web service using WebServiceTemplate. I am able to call the service using SOAP UI with following input and getting the correct response.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:abc="http://abc.hs.com/">
      <soapenv:Header>
                <version>1<version>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <abc:getUser>
         <userId>pan</userId>
      </abc:getUser>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But when calling using WebserviceTemplate as below:

```
public String getUser(String userId) {
        List<String> detail = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            template = new WebServiceTemplate(marshaller);
            String requestPayload = getXmlInput();// This is same xml I am sending using SOAPUI 
            StreamSource source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(requestPayload));
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
            template.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult("http://localhost:8080/HERSvc/InsService", source,
                    new WebServiceMessageCallback() {
                        public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage message) throws IOException {
                        TransportContext context = TransportContextHolder.getTransportContext();
                        HttpUrlConnection connection = (HttpUrlConnection) context.getConnection();
                        connection.addRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
                        connection.addRequestHeader("soapAction", "");
                }
            },result);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
```

I am getting following error at server side: `E org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine receive The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is http://localhost:8080/HERSvc/InsService and the WSA Action = . If this EPR was previously reachable, please contact the server administrator.`

Client side error message : There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).

After going through `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981379/the-endpoint-reference-epr-for-the-operation-not-found-is` I added Content-Type and soapAction in header

NOTE: I suspect problem is with my requestPayload which is not formed properly. It is same string used in SOAP UI. It seems the input is transformed as Body

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:abc="http://abc.hs.com/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header>
    <version>1<version>
</soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <abc:getUser>
            <userId>pan</userId>
        </abc:getUser>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: Remove your customization, that breaks things. You should be adding a proper soap-action and Spring WebServices has out-of-the-box support for that.

Comment: At first i called template.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult("http://localhost:8080/HERSvc/InsService", source, result); without WebServiceMessageCallback() still I was getting error operation-not-found-. So i added header

Comment: there is also another method marshalSendAndReceive. Did you try with that? and also see if you have proper imports

Comment: Just use `marshalSendAndReceive` and add the correct SoapAction header. Just adding an empty header is obviously not the right value. The WSDL contains the correct value to set for the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that required Header was not formed properly. Initially I wasn't able to create objectPayload, so unable to use marshalSendAndReceive. So, to create proper objectPayload I used my wsdl to generate ObjectFactory from command prompt and then imported all the objects created to the project. Use marshalSendAndReceive as follows

```
wsimport -d generated http://example.org/stock?wsdl

public User getUser(User user) {
        try {
            template = new WebServiceTemplate(marshaller);
            JAXBElement<?> response =  (JAXBElement<?>)template.marshalSendAndReceive("http://localhost:8080/HERSvc/InsService", 
            new ObjectFactory().createGetUser(user),
                    new WebServiceMessageCallback() {
                        public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage message) {
                            try {
                                SoapMessage soapMessage = (SoapMessage)message;
                                SoapHeader header = soapMessage.getSoapHeader();
                                StringSource headerSource = new StringSource("<version>1.0</version>");
                                        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
                                        transformer.transform(headerSource, header.getResult());
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                }) ;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        GetUserResponse responseObject = (GetUserResponse)response.getValue();
    User user = responseObject.getReturn();
    }
```